# Recoger un entero de un fichero

Tags: c++

El programa consiste en escribir un numero (en este caso 1) en un fichero y a continuación, abrir el fichero y mostrarlo en pantalla. El problema consiste en que no se como recoger un int.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c;

    ofstream ficheroSalida;
    ficheroSalida.open("almacen.txt");
    ficheroSalida << 1 ;
    ficheroSalida.close();

    fstream ficheroEntrada;
    ficheroEntrada.open("almacen.txt");
    if(ficheroEntrada.is_open())
    {
        while(!ficheroEntrada.eof())
        {
            ficheroEntrada.get(c);
        }
        cout << c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes capturar lo que viene del fichero como un string, luego tienes que convertir ese string a entero con la función atoi(string); de la librería cstdlib.

```
int c;
string r;

ofstream ficheroSalida;
ficheroSalida.open("almacen.txt");
ficheroSalida << 1 ;
ficheroSalida.close();

fstream ficheroEntrada;
ficheroEntrada.open("almacen.txt", ios_base::in);
if(ficheroEntrada.is_open())
{
    while(!ficheroEntrada.eof())
        getline(ficheroEntrada, r);
    c = atoi(r.c_str());
    cout << c;
}
return 0;
```

No olvides agregar la librería cstdlib